# JDBC query returning zero when using simple arithmetic operations and alias even though the data in table is not zero

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc

I am building a web portal through android and a query i am running through JDBC drivers is returning 0 where data should not be zero.

This is the query:

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery("select it.itcod,      it.itnam,     it.packn, it.tradp, " +
                    "sum(nvl(itd.slbox,0) - nvl(itd.srbox,0) - nvl(itd.brbox,0) - nvl(itd.gsbox,0)) as sbox, " +
                    "sum(nvl(itd.slbbx,0) - nvl(itd.srbbx,0) - nvl(itd.brbbx,0) - nvl(itd.gsbbx,0)) as sbbx, " +
                    "SUM(NVL(itd.PRBOX,0) - NVL(itd.RPBOX,0) - NVL(itd.TRBOX,0)) as pbox, " +
                    "SUM(NVL(itd.PRBBX,0) - NVL(itd.RPBBX,0) - NVL(itd.TRBBX,0)) as pbbx " +
                    "from items it " +
                    "LEFT join item_daily itd " +
                    "on  (it.cocod = itd.cocod " +
                    "and it.itcod = itd.itcod " +
                    "and ITD.ddate between " + fdate + " and " + tdate + ")" +
                    "WHERE IT.COCOD = " + COCOD +
                    "AND IT.DCODE = " + DCODE +
                    "AND NVL(IT.FREZE,'N')!='Y' " +
                    "group by it.cocod, it.itcod, it.itnam, it.packn, " +
                    "       it.tradp, it.pkqty, it.dcode, it.freze, " +
                    "       it.ishow, it.sltax, it.dcont, it.mcode, " +
                    "       it.nwcod " +
                    "order by itnam ");
```

I have tried using resultsetmetadata but that does not work either.

Comment: can you run it thru sql plus/ sql developer and see if gets you desired output?

Comment: i ran it through keep tool and it does give me the desired result so the i know for sure that the data is not there @pahariayogi

Comment: Be aware that if fdate, tdate, COCOD, or DCODE are from user input then the query is susceptible to a SQL injection attack.  Consider using a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be careful  to this line

```
 + fdate + " and " + tdate
```

because you should use like this:

```
" .. to_date('"+fdate+"','***your_date_format') and to_date('"+fdate+"','***your_date_format')"
```

Comment: i have been running this query through keep tool and the data return fine.. i have tried this as well but this throws other exceptions

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: I did, still returning zero, this bug has really put a dead end to my application, would love any other solutions

Comment: what is your exactly query? can you write it which you run it on editor? without params ?